# Hide ALL heading stars in org mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to visually hide ALL stars in emacs org mode headers? T.g. the text

```
* MY HEADER 1
my text 1
* MY HEADER 2
my text 1
```

to be displayed as

```
MY HEADER 1
   my text 1
   MY HEADER2 
     my text 2
```

PS I prefer to highlight/fontify all header line and to use org-indent-mode so it's visually headers without start would loook different than common text

Comment: Does this link resolve your questions?  "*How to hide leading stars in windowless emacs org-mode?*":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/how-to-hide-leading-stars-in-windowless-emacs-org-mode

Comment: No, org-hide-leading-stars leaves one star, e.g. displays "* MY HEAD" instead of  "**** MY HEAD"

Comment: FWIW: I do this with `outline-mode`, for (editable) Info tables of contents. In Info, links use `*note` for such a link, and the code in `Info-fontify-node` hides that `*note` part according to the value of variable `Info-hide-note-references`. It just loops, finding such a link, and then does this, where match level 3 is the text `*note`: `(add-text-properties (match-beginning 3) (match-end 3) '(invisible t front-sticky nil rear-nonsticky t))`. You could do something similar, searching for `^[*] ` and making just that text invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Hooking the following function `org-mode-hide-stars` worked for me. This is based off of this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9wukv8/comment/e9pkggv/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) response.

```
(defun org-mode-hide-stars ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("^\\*+ "
      (0
       (prog1 nil
         (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                            'face (list :foreground
                                        (face-attribute
                                         'default :background)))))))))
(use-package org
  :hook
  (org-mode . org-mode-hide-stars)
  :ensure t 
  )
```