# How to hide leading stars in org-mode when in terminal mode

Tags: emacs, configuration, org-mode

When using org-mode in emacs running in terminal mode (`emacs -nw`), I cannot hide the leading stars in my headings:

[image: leading starts not hidden]

I have seen some similar questions which either:

- [did not have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318618/hide-all-heading-stars-in-org-mode-in-emacs) or
- [did not have an answer that worked for me](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/how-to-hide-leading-stars-in-windowless-emacs-org-mode)

The attached image was after trying the suggested remedies *(minus changing my contrast as that leads to other problems)*.

Is there any way to have these leading starts hidden?

Comment: What value did you set the `org-hide` to?

Comment: I current value was "white" so I tried "black".

Comment: foreground or backgournd?

Comment: Both of them are set to "black"

Comment: Isn't the `inverse` on?

Comment: It was off but turning it on does not achieve the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208558/discussion-between-j1n3l0-and-choroba).

Comment: Is it because you have fancy bullets?  Try turning off whatever is doing that.

Comment: No that has no effect.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you managed to get this fixed?

Comment: No, not yet. I have essentially given up on this.